Setting up loopback device on windows 10
I have VirtualBox Windows 10 VM.
Im trying to install Oracle 10g on it.
Unfortunately the install verification didn't pass. It says I need a Loopback device and I should make it first.
Now, while I was able to install the device, I have no idea how to make it the first on the list.
Windows asset up to use DHCP and this is the reason for the error.
How do I solve my problem?

Please not add phrases like “TIA” to your question. It will be removed. You don’t have to ask for help. You do need to be specific on what you want help fixing. By submitting a question you automatically are asking us to help, so “asking for someone to help”, is just noise that will be removed. Be clear in what your problem is exactly makes it easier to write an answer to directly address that question or problem.

@Ramhound, I wish I can travel around the world and meet every single person here on SO in order to say Hi, How are you". That way I will already know you guys f2f but even then I will probably continue to write Hi, All in the beginning. I just don't understand this - it's a basic courtesy to say Hi in order to initiate a conversation. And then say Thanx in advance at the end.

Please stop using “Hi All,” and other phrases you have been using, they will be removed, they are unnecessary, and it’s extra work on every potential editor. You now know it’s unnecessary. So I won’t mention it again.  I will of course also remove those unnecessary noises, without any comment going forward, I of course don’t want extra work.

I found simple procedure (source):

Open Device Manager

Select Network Adapters
(Otherwise you will not see the menu item mentioned in the next step)

Open Action menu

Select Add legacy hardware, click Next

Select Install the hardware that I manually select from a list
(Advanced), click Next

Select Network adapters, click Next

Select Microsoft in the left pane

Select Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter in the right pane, click Next:
Windows 8 Device Manager

Click Next and Finish untill the installation is done


